# How to disable browser's pop-up window with inscription "Attention required" when i enter to APEX local server?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-xml-db

I need your help. I please you. Recently i installed the Oracle APEX 3.2.1 using next instructions from:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nj8gXyA3Z4w

. And after that , i have already changed a password for APEX user. And when i'm trying to enter on the my local server then is occuring dialog box with description "Attention Requeried"(watch the picture. Don't wonder what dialog window's language is russian. This is an autentification form what shouldn't be generally. It's messing me to log in in the APEX).

[Attention Required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T38Di.png)
How to avoid that window ?

One people said , what problem in my XML DB. And then i wanted to reinstall that , but in my apex folder haven't file catqm.sql for that operation. If my problem in XML DB exclusively , so i please you to give me an file catqm.sql and will reinstall XML DB or yourself talk: how to repair this.

What me do and how to repair ? Please answer. If you need more data about the my problem , so say me and i will add the more of description. I will wait the answer with no patience )))).

Dmitri

Comment: That video is from 2014. You are probably better off following the current installation instructions: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/install.50/e39144/toc.htm

Comment: Are you sure what instruction is fully correct ? Because i want to install NOT apex 5.0 , but only apex 3.2.1 .

Comment: That's a very old version. From memory I think you need to allow anonymous access to xdb, refer here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/643846?tstart=0

Comment: Jeffrey. It is working . Only left to log in me over apex on the local web page and all )). A lot of thank you. . I hope what god grant you the solid health ))))